# Call to a member function save() on array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get an input from a form and save it to the db. The form includes an image upload.

When I try the code below (that's all wrong I know) I get "Call to a member function save() on array". I'm not sure how to amend the code to make it right

**Controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    //
    $input = $request->all();
    $input->save();
    if($file = $request->file('image')){
      $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      if($file->move('image', $name)){
        $post = new Gallery();
        $post->image = $name;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.gallery.index');
      };
    };
}
```

**Create Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<h1>UPLOAD PICTURES</h1>
{!! Form::open(['method' =>'POST', 'action'=> 'GalleryController@store', 
'files'=>true, 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('Picture:') !!}
  {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('species_id', 'Species:') !!}
 {!! Form::select('species_id', [''=>'Choose Species'] + $species, null, 
 ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('name', 'Image Title:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('patreon', 'Patreon Image?:') !!}
  {!! Form::select('patreon', array(1 =>'Yes', 0=>'No'), 0,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::submit('Upload Image', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
@endsection
```

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gallery extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
      'image',
      'species_id',
      'name',
      'tag',
      'patreon'
    ];
    public function species(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Species');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$input = $request->all(); $input->save();` To what end? You haven't made any changes. And `$input` is an array of objects, not the object you save to.

Comment: The error is on the line with `$input->save();` because `$request->all()` returns a map with the post fields...

Comment: See - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem lies within this code block.

```
$input = $request->all();
$input->save();
```

`$request->all();` returns an array of the inputs from the request. Now `$input` is an array, why you are trying to call `->save();` on an array, i don't know, but if you remove that line it will work.

Answer (score 0):

it says that you got your object, but in array

```
$foo = 
[ 0 => yourObject ]
```

if you got only one item, just do

> `$foo = end($foo)`

if you have multiple items in result array, jus iterate it over foreach loop